# Including original Msg & Signature in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem.replyAll

Tags: c#, office-interop

Im trying to include original message and signature in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem.replyAll but nothing seems available for the purpose. Anyone who can help :( Thanks